# CSS Property View Port Height Not Being Set

Tags: css, wordpress

There is a main CSS file (style .css) in my WordPress theme. I'm trying to reduce the height of an image banner by reducing the value oh the height: 100vh; to height: 50vh;

I changed it to 50vh but the banner height doesn't change. But when I right-click on Chrome->Inspect and change it there, then it works. Can anybody tell me if it works in the chrome inspect then why doesn't it work in the actual CSS file? Is any other way in which I can reduce the 100vh to 50vh?

Comment: If you change the height value in your css, and then use Chrome dev tools to inspect it; is it being overridden by a different height value?

Comment: Clear your css/js cache from browser side after publish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add !important to the end of the style.

```
element {
    height: 50vh!important;
}
```